# OSX Preview HIGHLIGHTER makes for bad PRINT quality

Tags: preview

There appears to be a funny bug in Preview.app 5.0.3 (504.1):

I took a few PDF pages of normal black text, used Preview's yellow highlight functionality, and printed it on a B&W HP Laserjet.

The pages that don't contain any highlights look normal.  But the pages that do are printed in a strange 'jittery' low-quality -- all of it, not just the words that are highlighted.

I've seen this happen with a variety of different PDFs that I've highlighted using Preview.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing here... but I suspect that Preview uses a jpg of the pdf onto which it'd add the highlight. The high compression used used by Preview in this process would be where the low-quality comes from.

How to get around it? Use the annotation highlight function in Acrobat Reader instead if you can. Sorry, not a solution but a work-around! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you insist using he Preview for PDF files.

I assume you do not have the Adobe reader installed.

Install it (Adobe reader XI) and use its function for highlighting.

But if you insist using the Preview, please set it up via Print screen.

Print > Color matching > select > in Printer.